# UITableView null size inside UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints

I had a uitableview inside a uiviewcontroller with autolayout constraints to change its size according to the main view. 
Once I embedded everything inside a uiscrollview to manage the keyboard covering part of the tableview, the bottom space to superview constraint stopped working and the tableview height is always 0.
I debugged the view and that specific constraint is disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: First, you can't use auto layout to layout the insides of a scrollview. Second, why are you putting a UITableView inside a scrollview?

Comment: I have a view controller with some uiimageviews and a tableview. The tableview is a form to complete and has textfields. When the keyboard appears, it covers many of the fields the user is trying to interact with.